# Marshalling and Unmarshalling in Java Server/Client

Tags: java, server, arrays, marshalling

I have some questions on how to set up a server with marshalling and unmarshalling capabilities. I have been given code by my instructor to implement the marshalling and unmarshalling, as well as sending and receiving the data through TCP. [Here is my code.](https://gist.github.com/a6b07d8e489d3d7cb894.git)

**First**, since I need to send/receive for both a server and client I assume I need to have the files (TCPSender.java, TCPReceiver.java, and WireFormatWidget.java - the marshalling/unmarshalling class) in the same source path as both the client and the server. Based upon the code, that seems as if that's all I need to do. I don't seem to have to create any packages. Does that look right?

**Second**, since my server/client(s) will be running a marshalling/unmarshalling class, I can output data via string, and then the WireformatWidget will translate it in between the console print-outs.

**Last** I'm not 100 percent sure on the value of sending via byte arrays, could someone give me a run-down of why this is useful? Also, perhaps send me to a their trusted source on learning about them? I am consulting Java docs at the moment, and it is helpful, but I would like something more specific to my application. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need a `Widget` to read/write between your client(s) and server.

I'd suggest using [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) if you want to control the marshalling / unmarshalling. There's also the marker interface [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) if you want to let Java automatically control the marshalling / unmarshalling.

As for why you might need to convert the state of a `Widget` to a `byte[]`; it's generally so you can write them to and/or read them from somewhere (like a disk, or a remote client). Basically, it is one mechanism to restore the state of an instance programatically. Other such mechanism involves generating human readable representation (e.g. [XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [JSON](https://github.com/google/gson)).

Finally, for better help faster, please include your code in your question. Making it a link to an off-site image makes it unlikely to be read.